# Add number on mouse click?

Tags: python

Trying to create a simple script that adds a number to "a starting symbol" every time I click.
Its a small macro to name stuff like: A1, A2, A3, etc.
Hence the reason I'm trying to type this after a click.

The print function works!

```
print(message, number)
```

But when I try to type it, I get often no error and sometimes: "*TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable*"

```
pyautogui.typewrite(number)
```

Here the full script:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import pyautogui
import time

message = input('Start number ...')
number = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        global number
        global message
        number = number + 1
        print(message, number)
        # pyautogui.typewrite(number)

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

If anyone here knows what I'm doing wrong, please let me know :)
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your number to string:

```
pyautogui.typewrite(str(number))
```